# AWS: Transaction - while not commit get registered data

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, transactions, mysql-python

now I am writing an API using AWS lambda with python. but I having a problem.

below is flow:

1. using cursor to inserted data
2. while not commit get id of inserted data(1) for insert in to another tables

here is my code:

```
sqlPjInsert = "INSERT INTO PROJECT(PRJ_NAME,TEST_TGT,DESCRIPTION,PRJ_STATUS) VALUE(%s,%s,%s,%s);"
cursor.execute(sqlPjInsert, (p_name, p_url, p_desc, p_stt))
affectedProject = cursor.rowcount
print("Date fetched: " + results)
if affectedProject == 1:
    #conn.commit()
    logger.info("PROCESS: get project")
    sqlPjGet = "SELECT * FROM PROJECT WHERE PRJ_NAME='"+p_name+"' ORDER BY INS_DTTM DESC LIMIT 1;"
    cursor.execute(sqlPjGet)
    for row in getInsertedPJ:
         h_answer_prj_id = row["PRJ_ID"]
         logger.info("PROCESS: get project id" + h_answer_prj_id)

    /*Using h_answer_prj_id for insert into another tables*/
        ....
conn.commit()
```

More detail:
i have two tables:

1:Project

2:Answer

in my API after inserted an Project then i get Project ID from inserted data. and i using Project ID for insert new data into Answer table. after the all inserted i commit data. if have any exception then I call Rollback function.

Comment: Please provide more detail of the specifics.

Comment: yup. ihave two tables:
1:Project
2:Answer

in my API after inserted an Project then i get Project ID from inserted data. and i using Project ID for insert new data into Answer table.

after the all inserted i commit data. if have any exception then i call Rollback function